# if using type command displays a command is hashed, how to know is it a builtin command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My shell is bash, and when I execute

```
type env
```

it displays like that

```
env is hashed (/usr/bin/env)
```

For this condition, how to know is a command bulitin using the shell command rather than checking the manual.

Comment: Well if it is a builtin, it would say `<name> is a shell builtin`. For example, try `type cd`

Comment: More info on "X is hashed" [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105876/what-does-rm-is-hashed-mean). But as Mihir said, if it's hashed it's a non-builtin binary

Comment: You can also use `-t` to get a response from `type` that (in the case of a builtin) would be the single word `builtin` which would make it easier if you wanted to do a conditional statement in a script.

Comment: @borrible nice one, it also apparently has the same output (`file`) for binaries whether they're hashed or not

Comment: Thanks for all your help! For the more, which I realised is that the builtin command binary file cannot be hashed, because cannot get its full path, is it correct?

Comment: @amonhao not really, it's because it doesn't make sense to hash builtins. You could consider they're already hashed, as in "the shell already knows what you're talking about when you say `cd`" (because it implements them itself; that's what builtin means). For non-builtin commands on the other hand, the shell doesn't know them and has to look for a binary on the filesystem, by scanning all the directories listed in your `$PATH` variable. The hash avoids this costly process by remembering commands you've already used and their location.